# How to get past the Syslinux copyright screen

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, usb-creator

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my computer (Running Windows 7-64 bit on an Acer 5742-6331 laptop). I downloaded both 14.04.2 and 15.04. I put the 14.04 image on a USB with Universal USB Installer, version 1.9.6.0.

Unfortunately, every time I tried booting up with the USB, the computer got stuck on the Syslinux copyright screen. I tried 15.04 after that, but the same thing. Then I downloaded Unetbootin and put the Ubuntu 14.04 image on my USB with that. Same thing.

Forum posts are telling me that it's probably the syslinux.cfg file, but I have no idea what it's supposed to look like.

The text currently states:

```
default menu.c32 prompt 0 menu title UNetbootin timeout 100

label unetbootindefault menu label Default kernel /ubnkern append initrd=/ubninit file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --

label ubnentry0 menu label Help kernel /ubnkern append initrd=/ubninit

label ubnentry1 menu label Try Ubuntu without installing kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --

label ubnentry2 menu label Install Ubuntu kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash --

label ubnentry3 menu label Check disc for defects kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash --

label ubnentry4 menu label Test memory kernel /install/mt86plus append initrd=/ubninit

label ubnentry5 menu label Boot from first hard disk kernel /ubnkern append initrd=/ubninit

label ubnentry6 menu label Try Ubuntu without installing kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash --

label ubnentry7 menu label Install Ubuntu kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash --

label ubnentry8 menu label OEM install (for manufacturers) kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true --

label ubnentry9 menu label Check disc for defects kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi append initrd=/casper/initrd.lz boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash --
```

If anyone could help me out, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: Did you md5sum check the downloaded iso?
  See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM
  Check the number against the listing in the link for your release listed at
  http://releases.ubuntu.com under the MD5SUMS link.

Answer (score 3):

[Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) is a utility that helps format and create bootable USB flash drives, such as USB keys/pendrives, memory sticks, etc. Rufus can be especially useful in cases where bootable media created in Windows by other GUI Linux live USB creators such as Universal USB Installer and UNetbootin gets stuck and won't boot. Rufus is the recommended application at the official Ubuntu website for making a bootable live Ubuntu USB on Windows. Rufus can also make a bootable Windows 10 USB.

#### System requirements

Windows XP or later, 32-bit or 64-bit

#### Usage

1. You will need a 2GB or larger USB flash drive and an Ubuntu iso file. For Ubuntu 18.04 and later the USB flash drive should be 4GB or larger. Download the Rufus executable file for Windows from [here](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and run it. No installation is necessary.
2. Select your device volume label.
3. Click the drive image to select the Ubuntu .iso file.
4. If it's an Ubuntu .iso, Rufus will automatically select the FAT32 file system.
5. Click *Start*, and a message will appear saying that all of your USB data will be deleted and the USB drive will be formatted.
6. Click *OK*.
7. Click *Close*.

Rufus persistent storage partition is supported in 19.10 and later. Please upgrade Rufus to version 3.9 or later.

[image: Rufus persistent storage]